# Can't access data from a nested array in a JSON in swift

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct, nested

I have a JSON with a nested array, I'd like to access one of the data contained in that nested array, but I have no idea how I could do that.

I'm developing an IOS App and try to parse some data from a (local for now) JSON. I want to display some of the data to the user.

This is what my JSON looks like:

```
{
"format": "json",
"data": [
    {
        "type": "channel",
        "id": "789",
        "updated_at": "2019-05-03 11:32:57",
        "unread_count": 3,
        "title": "title",
        "context": "search",
        "relationships": {
            "recipients": [
                {
                    "type": "user",
                    "rating": 5,
                    "is_spotlighted": false,
                    "id": 123,
                    "participant_id": 456
                }
            ],
        }
    }
}
```

for now I access the different value with:

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let format: String
    let data: [ChannelData]
}

struct ChannelData: Decodable {
    let title, type, id, context, updatedAt: String
    let unreadCount: Int
    let relationships: Relationships
}

struct Relationships: Decodable {
    let recipients: [Recipient]
}

struct Recipient: Decodable {
    let type: String
    let id: Int
    let participantId: Int
    let isSpotlighted: Bool
    let rating: Double
}
```

The data I want to access to is "rating"

This is what my viewDidLoad() looks like :

```
var chatList = [ChannelData]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "channels", withExtension: "json")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let result = try! decoder.decode(Root.self, from: data)
    chatList = result.data
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

When in another function I try to access to the rating through:

```
let currentChat = chatList[indexPath.row]
cell.Name.text = currentChat.relationships.recipients
```

Nothing is shown when I try to get other parameters after .recipients. I'm a beginner using JSON and more or less using Swift too.

Comment: I recall that to use `Decodable` the attributes have to be written exactly the same as that in the JSON, ie if its `is_spotlighted`, then it has to be `is_spotlighted` when u declare the struct.

Comment: @Koh That's wrong. The key decoding strategy [`convertFromSnakeCase`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsondecoder/keydecodingstrategy/convertfromsnakecase) handles the conversion pretty smartly.

Answer (score 0):

`Relationships` contains one property `recipients` with the type `[Recipient]`. You could use `.first` to access the first `Recipient` object from the array. Then you can get any property from `Recipient` object

```
cell.Name.text = currentChat.relationships.recipients.first?.rating
```